# Dropdown menu automatically closes when you open it on iPhone (Bootstrap v3.3.1)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just been working on the backend on a new site when I've noticed a big error on the front-end and I'm stuck trying to work this one out.

I have an old version of the site that I've been working on and have moved and tidied up the rest of it on a new version. However when I go to the Safari Browser on the iPhone it doesn't load the dropdown menu correctly on the new one, despite copying the website header and footer (which contains the same menu) across from the old site.

When you push the menu, it will open then immediately close on an iPhone. However chrome and firefox web browsers works fine. I've tried to look at forums and change the bootstrap code but nothing seems to work. It only does it on the responsive menu dropdown.

Oddly thou, the old site has the full width dropdown menu, and the new site sticks on the right hand side (not full width) as if it hasn't loaded correctly.

**Old Site (Working)**

[old.hidden-network.co.uk](http://old.hidden-network.co.uk)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?> | Social Research Unit</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
    <link rel="icon" href="/inc/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/inc/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/inc/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/inc/css/screen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="/inc/css/print.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="/inc/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/inc/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HEADER START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top dartNavbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <?php $lang->getLinks(); ?>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed dartMenuButton" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"
                    data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    Menu
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-brand dartNavbar-brand" href="/">
                    <div class="titleShapes">
                        <span class="DataUnit" title="Data Unit"></span>
                        <span class="WhatWorksUnit" title="What Works Unit"></span>
                        <span class="InnovationUnit" title="Innovation Unit"></span>
                        <span class="PlaceUnit" title="Place Unit"></span>  
                    </div>
                    <img src="/inc/img/logo.full.png" alt="Dartington Social Research Unit" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse no-transistion">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li<?php $if->active('about'); ?>>
                        <a href="/About/">About</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('process'); ?>>
                        <a href="/methods/">Methods</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('projects'); ?>>
                        <a href="/projects/">Projects</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('resources'); ?>>
                        <a href="/resources/">Resource</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('contact'); ?>>
                        <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="youtube">
                        <a href="https://youtube.com/socialresearchunit" target="_blank">
                            <div class="icon"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="twitter">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/socialresunit" target="_blank">
                            <div class="icon"></div>                        
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- HEADER ENDS -->

    <!-- CONTENT STARTS -->
    <div class="content">
```

**New Site (Not Working)**

[new.hidden-network.co.uk](http://new.hidden-network.co.uk)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?> | Social Research Unit</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
    <link rel="icon" href="/inc/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/inc/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/inc/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/inc/css/screen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="/inc/css/print.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="/inc/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/inc/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/inc/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/inc/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HEADER START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top dartNavbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <?php $lang->getLinks(); ?>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed dartMenuButton" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"
                    data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <div class="icon-bar icon-bar-top"></div>
                    <div class="icon-bar"></div>
                    <div class="icon-bar"></div>
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-brand dartNavbar-brand" href="/">
                    <div class="titleShapes">
                        <span class="DataUnit" title="Data Unit"></span>
                        <span class="WhatWorksUnit" title="What Works Unit"></span>
                        <span class="InnovationUnit" title="Innovation Unit"></span>
                        <span class="PlaceUnit" title="Place Unit"></span>  
                    </div>
                    <img src="/inc/img/logo.full.png" alt="Dartington Social Research Unit" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" />
                    <img src="/inc/img/logo.full.notext.png" alt="Dartington Social Research Unit" class="hidden-md hidden-lg" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse no-transistion">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li<?php $if->active('about'); ?>>
                        <a href="/about/">About</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('methods'); ?>>
                        <a href="/methods/">Methods</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('projects'); ?>>
                        <a href="/projects/">Projects</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('resources'); ?>>
                        <a href="/resources/">Resource</a>
                    </li>

                    <li<?php $if->active('contact'); ?>>
                        <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="youtube">
                        <a href="https://youtube.com/socialresearchunit" target="_blank">
                            <div class="icon"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="twitter">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/socialresunit" target="_blank">
                            <div class="icon"></div>                        
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="search">
                        <a onClick="search()">
                            <div class="icon"></div>
                            <span>
                                <input type="text" id="search" data-search="Search" />
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- HEADER ENDS -->

    <!-- CONTENT STARTS -->
    <div class="content">
```

Comment: The site works on a desktop browser, does it work on your iPhone?

Comment: .navbar-right {position: absolute;} remove this style.

Answer (score 0):

> .navbar-right {position: absolute;} remove this style. –  vel

This worked great, thankyou vel !